# Generating the points of a circle

Tags: r

I'm just playing around with the image of circles under the complex map exp(z).

I couldn't find a built in R function to generate the points on a circle of given radius so I wrote one myself (integrating the equations of motion numerically):

```
# Integration points:
N <- 10000
e <- 0.001
dt <- seq(0, e*(N-1), by=e)

Rp = pi         # radius of point circle
Rv = pi          # radius of vector circle

# Initial conditions:
px <- c(Rp)
py <- c(0)

vx <- c(0)
vy <- c(Rv)

Rp <- c()
Rv <- c()

ax <- c()
ay <- c()


for (i in(2:N)) {

Rp[i-1] <- sqrt(px[i-1]^2 + py[i-1]^2)
Rv[i-1] <- sqrt(vx[i-1]^2 + vy[i-1]^2)

ax[i-1] <- -(Rv[i-1]^2/Rp[i-1]^2)*px[i-1]  # acceleration toowards
ay[i-1] <- -(Rv[i-1]^2/Rp[i-1]^2)*py[i-1]  # center of circle

px[i] <- px[i-1] + e*vx[i-1] # dp_x = epsilon * v_x
py[i] <- py[i-1] + e*vy[i-1] # dp_y = epsilon * v_y

vx[i] <- vx[i-1] + e*ax[i-1]   # dv_x = epsilon * a_x
vy[i] <- vy[i-1] + e*ay[i-1]   # dv_y = epslon * a_y
}

complex(real=px,imaginary=py)
```

This seems like a lot of work just to get a circle, and the program is slow. Is there a built in R function to do this for me?

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(cbind(px,py))
plot(exp(zs))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterize on angle:

```
circle_xy = function(n, r, close_loop = FALSE) {
  theta = seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = n + 1)
  if(!close_loop) theta = theta[-(n + 1)]
  cbind(x = r * cos(theta), y = r * sin(theta))
}
```

Gives x-y coords for `n` evenly spaced points on a circle of radius `r`. If `close_loop = TRUE`, the first point is repeated at the end. Takes about 0.2 seconds to generate 1MM points on my laptop.

And there is `plot.formula` function that would take that to an instantiation:

```
plot( y ~ x, data = xy<- circle_xy(100,1), type="l")
```